# Bit Error Probability

Tags: telecommunication

I want to ask for any help to solve my problem. I want to compute BER (Bit error rate) for a nine combination points as illustrated below. I used the computation for SER and then I convert it to BER, but the result was incorrect. Any site or suggestion please?
Many thanks
Othman

[image]

My code is:

```
clear all clc 
SNR = 0:40; 
SNRL = 10.^(SNR./10); 
Eb=1; 
sigma = sqrt(2*Eb./SNRL); 
d2 = 0.3; 
Pe = 14/9*erfc((d2)./sqrt(2*sigma.^2))+2/9*erfc((0)./sqrt(2*sigma.^2));
semilogy(SNR,Pe) grid on hold on
```

Comment: Please post the code that you tried, the result that it gave you, and the result that you expect.

Comment: clear all
clc
SNR = 0:40;
SNRL = 10.^(SNR./10);
Eb=1;
sigma = sqrt(2*Eb./SNRL);
d2 = 0.3;

Pe = 14/9*erfc((d2)./sqrt(2*sigma.^2))+2/9*erfc((0)./sqrt(2*sigma.^2));
semilogy(SNR,Pe)
grid on
hold on

Comment: @bwyn thanks for your quickly response, but I think the error in the computations! So if you know how could I calculate the BER for that constellation I will be thankful.